# Let $f$ be a bijection $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ , prove there exist positive integers such that...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Let $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ be a bijection.

Prove that there exist positive integers
$a < a + d < a + 2d$ such that $f(a) < f(a + d) < f(a + 2d).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let a = $f^{-1}(1)$.

Let $b_1 = f^{-1}(2)$.

1) If $b_1> a$ set $d = b_1-a$. $f(b_1 + d) > 2$. Therefore $$a < b_1 = a + d < b_1+ d = a + 2d$$ and $f(a) < f(a + d) < f(a +2d)$.

2) If $b_1< a$, let $b_2= f^{-1}(3)$ and proceed as in 1) above. Repeat as needed until $b_m= f^{-1}(m+1)> a$

There are only finitely many natural numbers less than a, so for some $k$ $b_k$ must be greater than $a$. Setting $d = b_k-a$ gives us our solution.

Comment: There are only a-1 natural numbers less than a. Each can be used at most once as the image of the inverse map. The repeat as needed will terminate after no more than a-1 iterations.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon No, in that case $b_1 = 1$ which doesn't work, and $b_2 = f^{-1}(3) = 5$ so $ d = 5 - 3 = 2$ and $f(3) = 1 < f(5) = 3 < f(7)$.

Comment: @themaker, you are right.  I have deleted my incorrect summary.